# sed RegEx matching for full/partial string

Tags: command-line, regex, sed

I'm having some trouble creating a RegEx string for `sed`.
I tested the expression with various online services, and there, it does succeed.
But not so with `sed`, unfortunately.

This is my testing `sed` expression:

```
echo "Windows" | sed -e 's/[Ww][Ii][Nn]([Dd][Oo][Ww][Ss])?/MATCH/g;'
```

And it should match either "Win" or "Windows" (And, of course, "WIN" and "windOwS", and so on). But it doesn't! (at least not with `sed`). *The problem is, that I cannot make the second part of the string optional.* The online RegEx testers work as expected, but I need it to work on the command line.

I know that there are a lot of RegEx flavours; so probably, I do not match the right one.
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression will work as an extended regular expression. Use `sed -E`:

```
echo "Windows Window" | sed -Ee 's/[Ww][Ii][Nn]([Dd][Oo][Ww][Ss])?/MATCH/g'
```

With GNU `sed` I can get the same effect without `-E` (i.e. when `sed` uses basic regular expressions) if I escape `(`, `)` and `?`:

```
echo "Windows Window" | sed -e 's/[Ww][Ii][Nn]\([Dd][Oo][Ww][Ss]\)\?/MATCH/g'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. All I was missing was escaping the question mark :-/ (I tried escaping the brackets) But I also learned that `sed -E` can simplify the whole situation.